# Looping over DataRow to compare current row data and previous row data

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, datarow

I need to iterate over a DataRow in gridview, to compare the values from the current row and previous row. Appreciate if someone could help on this issue. I'm new

I am currently iterating like this, but i dont know how to continue:

//Check if current row ACTIVITY = LOAD_A and previous row ACTIVITY = LOAD_B is true , then store the
value and do the sum calculation.

```
foreach (DataRow sda in dt.Rows)
 {

   if (sda.Field<string>("ACTIVITY") == "LOAD_A")
    {
  
    }
}
```

Comment: MoreLINQ's `Lag` or `Lead` (https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#lead) is where I would suggest you start.

Comment: Could you just store the field in a variable outside of the `foreach` and then access it as the "previous" value on subsequent iterations?

Comment: Hi devnull, i move the the field outside of foreach but it encounter error. sorry, i'm new in c#.

Answer (score 1):

As devNull already mentioned you can use a variable to hold the value of the previous iteration of the `foreach` loop.

This could look like this:

```
DataRow previousDr = null;
foreach (DataRow sda in dt.Rows)
{
    if (previousDr != null)
    {
        if (sda.Field<string>("ACTIVITY") == "LOAD_A" &&
            previousDr.Field<string>("ACTIVITY") == "LOAD_B")
        {
            //Store value und do calculation.
        }
    }
    previousDr = sda;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Oliver, need your help on this issue. i have one gridview, and i only want check the first row of column["ACTIVITY"] and last row of column ["ACTIVITY"] to get their date. Appreciate if you could help on this issue. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` statement and indexer property of DataRow to accomplish this

```
DataColumn column = table.Columns["ACTIVITY"];
for (int index = 1; index < table.Rows.Count; ++index)
{
    if (table.Rows[index - 1].Field<string>(column) == "LOAD_B" && // previous row
        table.Rows[index].Field<string>(column) == "LOAD_A")       // current row
    {
        // do somthing
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dmirtry, need your help on this issue. i have one gridview, and i only want check the  first row of column["ACTIVITY"] and last row of column ["ACTIVITY"]  to get their date. Appreciate if you could help on this issue. thansk.